i2S DAC output and Speaker signals
I am having a slight confusion regarding what type of wave/voltage range can the I2S DAC module can give. And what is the required voltage range needed for a speaker to give sound.

The i2S DAC module doesn't give any information if it can give a negative voltage or not when a binary number in 2s complement is transferred to the DAC.
Do speakers necessarily need an AC signal or I can work with the Alternating AC wave as well. I mean that doesn't go into the negative peak. Can it still give same sound effect. Because if the DAC isn't giving a negative voltage, then it means its working with an Alternating DC and it sounds well. Is there any difference of having an alternating wave with negative voltage as well, compared to an alternating DC wave.

Please let me know how to does this DAC output works because i have a .wav file with negative values as well.


The link is not to a module but to a chip data sheet. And it does give that information. It's a D-class amplifier chip. Technically, it cannot give out negative voltage which you asked - but that is not relevant and not really the question to ask as you don't need negative voltages. It drives the speaker with a H bridge so it can swap the terminal polarities which one is supply and ground, so it can drive AC current to the speaker like any normal audio amplifier.

Yes speakers need AC. They may even damage when presented with DC. But when you have answer to #1 already this is all that was relevant to answer.


Any amount of voltage gives some sound out of a speaker. Speakers are rated by their sensitivity, which defines how much dB SPL you get with some amount of input, typically 1W of power or in some cases 1Vrms of voltage. If you have a speaker with 80 dB SPL with 1 V of voltage, you get 80 dB less SPL with 80 dB less voltage.
So the range of voltage you need is between 0 and whatever is the tolerable voltage by your speaker as per it's rated or maximum wattage.

The output is a class D amplifier (H-bridge) so there will be a positive or negative average (over many switching cycles) voltage across the speakers. The longer term average (over many milliseconds) should be close to zero volts.
Speakers are typically (and best) driven from AC with zero average voltage.
The chip datasheet you linked contains this information:

The MAX98357A/MAX98357B DAI includes a DC blocker with a -3dB cutoff
at 3.7Hz.

So it looks like you can't command a DC output and get it anyway.
